# Upper bound of rational numbers in Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm attempting to prove the Riemann integrability of Thomae's function, defined by:

$$
f(x) =\begin{cases}
1 ,& x=0\\
1/n,& x = m/n \in\mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1], \text{written in lowest terms with $n > 0$}\\
0,& x\in \mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0, 1]
\end{cases}
$$

at the current step, I'm asked to find the upper bound for the number of elements in $E_n = \{x \in[0, 1] : f(x) \geq 1/n\}$ for natural number $n$

By Euler's Totient function (and intuition i suppose) that there are at most $n-1$ numbers relatively prime (and less than) to $n$. Since $|E_1|=1, |E_2|=2,\ldots$ I suppose $|E_{n+1}|\leq |E_n|+n$, or that $|E_n|\leq \frac{1}{2}(n-1)n-1$. This is correct?

Comment: For this well known function, Wikipedia is the one I go to first to find out more about the origin of the problem and various approaches to its solution like the one you are asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as *the* upper bound of $E_n$; each bounded set has infinitely many upper bounds. But it is clear that *an* upper bound of $E_n$ is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2-1$. This follows from the fact that$$E_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^n\left\{\frac km\,\middle|\,k\in\{0,1,\ldots,m\}\right\}.$$

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos is the following a valid approach to finishing the proof? First, I suppose $n^2$ is also an upper bound. Define a partition $P$ that is $\delta(t)$-fine, where $\delta(t)=\frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}$, so the upper sum $U(f,P)$ is less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}\cdot n^2$. Since the lower sum equals 0, $f$ is Riemann integrable by the Darboux criterion for integrability?

Comment: There are two problems there. In the first place, you cannot jump from “$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2-1$ is an upper bound” to “$n^2$ is an upper bound”. But that's not important; since you can use $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2-1$ instead of $n^2$ in what you wrote. In the second place, why would it follow that $U(f,P)<\frac\varepsilon{n^2}\cdot n^2$?

Comment: I dont think this is correct, but here is my thought process so far. Supposse lets redefine $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{(n+1)(n+2)}$, furthermore lets define $P$ such that there are $|E_n|$ subintervals. then $U(f,P)= \sum^n_{k=1} M_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$. Since the length of each interval is less than $\delta$. since $M_k \leq 1$, Thus $U(f,P)<$ number of subintervals times max length of the intervals($\delta$). Thus $U(f,P)<\left( \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-1\right)\frac{\varepsilon}{(n+1)(n+2)}< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I don't see where the inequality$$U(f,P)<\text{number of intervals}\cdot\delta$$comes from, even using the fact that you always have $M_k\leqslant1$.

Comment: would it be correct then to say $U(f,P)=\sum^{n}_{k=1}M_k(x_k-x_{k+1})<\sum^{n}_{k=1}M_k\cdot\delta < n\cdot \delta $? If that works, then I can just let $\delta=\varepsilon/n$ and the proof is complete?

Comment: Sure. I missed that. But anyway, that does not work. You are acting as if $n$ and $\delta$ are independent quantities. They are not. If your partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ consists of $n$ intervals with length $\delta$, then $\delta$ can only be equal to $\frac1n$. There is no other choice.